# Output an array of data collected from a file to a specific sheet in Master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The following code opens selected files, one at a time; if a file contains specific text string in `B11` (there are four variation: LS2A, LS1PRA, LS1A and LSM12), specified data from Sheet(1) of each file is copied into an array.  The search is performed by function “SearchFor” that is called in the main routine.

The array `ArrCopy` is filled with data from each file and should output into one of the four sheets in Master Workbook(SABI, SABII,LSM or LPRI&II). The output sheet is determined by the text string in `B11` of each file.

I can’t get data to output to Master workbook for some reason. I've tried Debug.Print each array item after it's filled and I can see that the array is filled with correct data but I can't get the values to tranfer to the master workbook. The code runs but nothing is outputed on the worksheet.

Please suggest how to make this work. Thanks

```
    Option Explicit
    Function SearchFor(output As Worksheet)


        Dim rowsCount As Long
        Dim NCBead1 As Long, NCBead2 As Long, PCBead1 As Long, PCBead2 As Long
        Dim IniString As String, IniVar As String
        Dim rngCell As Range, rngCell2 As Range
        Dim ArrCopy(1 To 9) As Variant
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim aCell As Range

        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     'extract initial after last underscore
       IniString = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B6").Value
       IniVar = Right(IniString, Len(IniString) - InStrRev(IniString, "_", , 1))
         Debug.Print IniVar

    'Debug.Print "LastRow = " & LastRow

    Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:="Trimmed Mean", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'Debug.Print "Trimmed Mean can be found in Row # " & aCell.Row
    'wb.Sheets(1).Select

       For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow)

                    If InStr(rngCell, "NC") > 0 Then

                    Debug.Print rngCell.Row
                    NCBead1 = rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    NCBead2 = rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

                    'End If

            Exit For

        End If

        Next rngCell

    For Each rngCell2 In ActiveSheet.Range("B" & aCell.Row & ":B" & LastRow)

                    If InStr(rngCell2, "PC") > 0 Then

                    Debug.Print rngCell2.Row
                    PCBead1 = rngCell2.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    PCBead2 = rngCell2.Offset(0, 2).Value

                    'End If

            Exit For

        End If

    Next rngCell2
        'Next searched
    Debug.Print NCBead2

    ArrCopy(1) = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value
    ArrCopy(2) = IniVar
    ArrCopy(3) = NCBead1
    ArrCopy(4) = NCBead2
    ArrCopy(5) = PCBead1
    ArrCopy(6) = PCBead2
    ArrCopy(7) = ActiveSheet.Range("B6").Value
    ArrCopy(8) = NCBead1
    ArrCopy(9) = NCBead1
    ' one row spanning several columns

Debug.Print "ArrCopy" & ArrCopy(1)
Debug.Print "ArrCopy" & ArrCopy(2)
Debug.Print "ArrCopy" & ArrCopy(3) 

    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = output.Range("A" & output.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Set Destination = Destination.Resize(1, UBound(ArrCopy))
    Destination.Value = ArrCopy


    End Function
    Sub openselectedfiles()

        Dim SaveDriveDir As String, MyPath As String, FnameInLoop As String
        Dim mybook As Workbook, thisWb As Workbook
        Dim N As Long, LstUnderSc As Long, ExtPer As Long, Varin As Long
        Dim Fname As Variant, ArrCopy(1 To 9) As Variant
        Dim output As Worksheet

        Dim inLS2A As Boolean, inLS1PRA As Boolean, inLS1A As Boolean, inLSM12 As Boolean

        Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

        ' Save the current directory.
        SaveDriveDir = CurDir

        ' Set the path to the folder that you want to open.
        MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

        ' Change drive/directory to MyPath.
        ChDrive MyPath
        ChDir MyPath

        ' Open GetOpenFilename with the file filters.

        Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", _
                Title:="Select a file or files", _
                MultiSelect:=True)
        ' Perform some action with the files you selected.
        If IsArray(Fname) Then
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .EnableEvents = False
            End With

            For N = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)

                ' Get only the file name and test to see if it is open.
                FnameInLoop = Right(Fname(N), Len(Fname(N)) - InStrRev(Fname(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
                If bIsBookOpen(FnameInLoop) = False Then

                    Set mybook = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(Fname(N))
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                        mybook.Sheets(1).Select

                        With ActiveSheet.Range("B11")
                            inLS2A = InStr(1, .Value, "LS2A", 1) > 0
                            inLS1PRA = InStr(1, .Value, "LS1PRA", 1) > 0
                            inLS1A = InStr(1, .Value, "LS1A", 1) > 0
                            inLSM12 = InStr(1, .Value, "LSM12", 1) > 0
                        End With

                        If inLS2A Then
                            Set output = thisWb.Sheets("SABII")
                            SearchFor output
                        ElseIf inLS1PRA Then
                            Set output = thisWb.Sheets("LPRI&II")
                            SearchFor output
                        ElseIf inLS1A Then
                            Set output = thisWb.Sheets("sabI")
                            SearchFor output
                        ElseIf inLSM12 Then
                            Set output = thisWb.Sheets("LSM")
                            SearchFor output
                        End If

                'End If
                        mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        Set mybook = Nothing
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "We skipped this file : " & Fname(N) & " because it is already open."
                End If
            Next N
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End If

        ' Change drive/directory back to SaveDriveDir.
        ChDrive SaveDriveDir
        ChDir SaveDriveDir
    End Sub


    Function bIsBookOpen(ByRef szBookName As String) As Boolean
    ' Contributed by Rob Bovey
        On Error Resume Next
        bIsBookOpen = Not (Application.Workbooks(szBookName) Is Nothing)
    End Function
```

Comment: There is too much code here for anyone to debug without some test data.  However, you say ArrCopy is loaded correctly so the error must exhibit in the block of code starting `Dim Destination As Range`.  Try `Debug.Print output.Name` `Debug.Print output.Parent.Name` and `Debug.Print Destination.Address`.  Are you writing to the required worksheet, workbook and range?

Comment: thanks, i figured it out.